# Regular expression to find start and end index of strings

Tags: regex, matlab

Say you are given an input string of

```
text = '8.*x.^21+x';
```

I'm trying to extract the start and end indices of the powers on the x variables using,

```
pattern = '(?<=\.\^)\d*|x';
[start,m_end]=regexp(text,pattern,'start','end')
```

start and m_end are given values of [4 7 10] and [4 8 10] respectively, but this leads to an error because the values of start and m_end should only be [7 10] and [8 10].
My regular expression is grabbing the first x that has a power as well as its power, but it shouldn't be.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you have has an alternation for any 'x' character: `|x`. If you want only the 'x' not followed by an exponentiation, you can add a negative lookahead assertion:

```
((?<=x\.\^)\d+)|(x(?!\.\^))
```

Also note the change from `*` to `+` quantifier on the `\d` character class specifier. This might be needed otherwise it will match an empty string.

Comment: this will grab the 2 in the string, making start = [7] and m_end = [8]; but, it will not grab the x as well (which would make start = [7 9] and m_end = [8 9].  Would I be better off running two regular expressions?

Comment: When I run it, it matches both the 2 and the 1, due to the \d+ being greedy. Looking at the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) it seems that the first output - "start" - contains all the info you need, and additional outputs only contain partial matches, so the [8 9] is expected as the partial match.

Comment: Wait, I guess I didn't understand... you want the 'x' included as well as its power?

Comment: yes, the problem I seem to be running into is when there is a single x (to the first power, except you don't write x.^1, I'm just trying to find the 'x' and then I replace it with a 1 later on)

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand. You can use a negative lookahead: `((?<=x\.\^)\d+)|(x(?!\.\^))`